# Connecting R to Microsoft SQL Server Using RODBC

Tags: r, sql-server-2008, odbc

I need help connecting to Microsoft SQL Server using an **RODBC** connection.
Here are some details:

```
Server Name: DC_SQL01 
Table Name: LiborTable
```

Once I have the data in R I know what to do from there. I have used

```
install.packages("RODBC")
```

to get the connectivity tools I need and that was straightforward.

Beyond that I am not sure of the next steps. I am assuming I need to set a new User Data Source and create the **ODBC** to the database I want to query.

Comment: check out ?odbcDriverConnect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Setup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879308(v=sql.105).aspx) the ODBC name first.

Then just run the following code (this assumes you use Windows authentication, otherwise include the username and password):

```
library(RODBC)
db    <- odbcConnect("YOUR_ODBC_NAME")
sql   <- "select * from [Your].[dbo].[tablename]"
df1   <- sqlQuery(db, sql)
```

Of course, you can change this specific SQL query to whatever you'd like.

Comment: I set up the ODBC Connection. The line odbcConnect("Libor") gives the error could not find function "odbcConnect"

Comment: @user3195446 That means you haven't loaded `RODBC`. You load packages with `library()`, so `library(RODBC)`. Alternately you can put the package name with 2 colons before each command you use from that package (i.e. `RODBC::`) but I don't recommend it in this case. I apologize, I assumed you had it loaded.

Comment: I am up and running - library(RODBC) channel <- odbcConnect("Libor").

Comment: @user3195446 Great! Glad it worked